# How can i force an user to select the file extension i want?

Tags: java

How can I force the user to save the file as .java or whatever?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I would like to use the JFileChooser option and throughout, force the user to select the file extension that I want.

Comment: Please provide more details. Your question "as is" could be answered as: _"by asking the user nicely"_.

Comment: How did they create the file? What are you using (other than the obvious, Java)

Comment: @Bart or by threatening them.

Comment: Put a gun to their head.

Comment: Voting to close, _with a vengeance._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the name with which the user is saving, get the substring from the lastindex of . and check with your extension type. If it is not matching then indicate the user to give the extension you want.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i force the user to save the file as .java or whatever?

```
fileName = fileName.endsWith(".java") ? fileName : fileName + ".java";
```

But that's probably not a good solution. If you can provide more detail in your question, you would probably get a better solution.